# Mulesoft on-prem cluster has node in 'unknown' state

Tags: cluster-computing, mulesoft

This happens from time to time, one of my nodes goes into an 'unknown' state. Where can I get technical information on what the cluster is? specifically ...

- what controls the state in the cluster?
- how does discovery and health information flow?
- and what is the mechanism for consensus?

My cluster is made of two machines around a shared Oracle database.

Comment: Where do you see the status? Runtime Manager?

Comment: Yes. Is there another place I should be looking?

Comment: That's fine, just wanted to understand from where are you getting the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The status of the cluster depends of connectivity between the nodes.
The status in Runtime Manager depends of connectivity between the Runtime Manager Agent, installed in each node, to Runtime Manager in the Anypoint Platform.Unknown status probably means the later. There are [several possible causes](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Troubleshooting-issues-managing-applications-or-servers-from-Runtime-Manager), like network connectivity issues, [bugs in older versions of the agent](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/runtime-manager-agent/runtime-manager-agent-release-notes), [expired certificates](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Applications-and-Servers-showing-as-unknown-and-disconnected-state-in-Anypoint-Runtime-Manager-due-to-expired-key-pair), etc.

I'm not quite sure to what consensus are you referring but I don't think there is a consensus mechanism that applies here. There is a [quorum mechanism](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/mule-high-availability-ha-clusters#distributed-data-center-clustering) but with only 2 nodes I don't think it is applicable.

Comment: I know my question was vage, but this pointed me in the right direction - thank you.